# Filtrar vlans de un comando

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
conf= "sh run int Eth102/1/32\r\r\n\r\n!Command: show running-config interface Ethernet102/1/32\r\n!Time: Tue Apr  9 12:49:55 2013\r\n\r\nversion 5.2(1)N1(9b)\r\n\r\ninterface Ethernet102/1/32\r\n  description CD1SW-BBTACCN5K-1\r\n  switchport mode trunk\r\n  switchport trunk allowed vlan 500,556,650,827,848\r\n  spanning-tree port type edge trunk\r\n  speed 1000\r\n  duplex full\r\n  no snmp trap link-status\r\n\r\n\rCD1SW-SSTACC3NK-1# "
```

Como podría sacar solo estos números de esta variable? y tenerlos en una lista.
500,556,650,827,848
Siempre estará después de switchport trunk allowed vlan. Lo he intentado con re.findall pero no se sido capaz... También podría ser que viniera así
500-550 y deneria coger de inicio a fin

Answer (score 2):

Con `re.findall()` puedes extraer toda secuencia de números separados por comas o guiones que aparezca tras las palabras "switchport trunk allowed vlan" mediante la siguiente expresión regular:

```
import re
resultado = re.findall(r"(?:switchport trunk allowed vlan *)([\d, -]+)", conf)
```

En este caso lo que va dentro del `(?:)` es un "grupo de no-captura. Buscamos que aparezcan esas palabras, pero no queremos capturarlas. El siguiente grupo entre paréntesis `([\d,-]+)` es lo que queremos capturar, que representa una secuencia de uno o más caracteres de la categoría dígitos, coma, espacio, o guión.

El resultado será una lista, con tantos elementos como veces haya aparecido el grupo "switchport trunk allowed vlan" seguido de números. En tu cadena de ejemplo aparece una sola vez, por lo que el resultado tendrá un solo elemento.

Ese elemento es el trozo de cadena que contiene ya solamente los números, comas y guiones. En este caso:

```
>>> resultado
['500,556,650,827,848']
```

Ahora deberías iterar por esa lista y para cada elemento, que es una cadena, dividirlo por las comas. Y para cada uno de los elementos resultantes (que será un número o un rango separado por guiones), convertirlo a un entero o secuencia de enteros, para finalmente recogerlos todos en una lista.

Esta parte es muy similar a [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/253791/7123) que hiciste hace un tiempo, y se puede reaprovechar parte de mi respuesta:

```
def traducir_rangos(lista):
  for elemento in lista:
    if "-" not in elemento:
      yield int(elemento)
    else:
      inicio, fin = elemento.split("-")
      yield from range(int(inicio), int(fin)+1)

lista_final = []
for caso in resultado:
  lista_final.extend(traducir_rangos(caso.split(",")))
```

Y en `lista_final` tendrías:

```
[500, 556, 650, 827, 848]
```

Otro ejemplo creado artificialmente para ver que funciona si la cadena contiene varios grupos en los que haya encajado y algún grupo contiene rangos separados por guiones, sería:

```
conf= "switchport trunk allowed vlan 200-204,303; mas cosas y otro switchport trunk allowed vlan 403, 500-510 y mas cosas"
```

Y el código anterior produciría ahora lo siguiente en `resultado`:

```
['200-204,303', '403, 500-510 ']
```

y lo siguiente en `lista_final`:

```
[200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 303, 403, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510]
```